# How can I let Linux and OS X users build an MSBuild-based project?

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild, cross-platform

I have a small open-source project written in C# that I generally use Visual Studio to edit, build, debug, etc. Of course, this means contributors to my repo must have a working copy of MSBuild on their machine for my build script to function.

This is no problem for Windows users, since Visual Studio installs it by default, but what about *nix users? Here are the options I've come up with so far:

- **Include MSBuild.exe in the repo.** While this looked like the obvious thing to do at first, I ran into a bunch of weird side effects because it was missing many of the configuration files I had forgotten to copy along with the executable. It also significantly bloated the size of my repo at 319 KB, so I'm feeling less sure about this option than I was before.
- **Download it from an online source.** [NuGet](https://api.nuget.org/downloads/nuget.exe) for example has an online place where you can download the executable, so you can automatically install it as part of your build script instead of hosting it in your repo. However, for MSBuild [you have to upload the package to a hosting site](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/build.sh#L69-L76), which seems very high-maintenance for me.
- **Force the user to have MSBuild installed at a particular path.** While this sounds easier to implement, it's prone to error because the user might copy-paste `MSBuild.exe` and forget to include those super-important configuration files, then wonder why the unit tests are suddenly not working. Besides, it's kinda annoying to have to do this when you already *have* the executable on disk.
- **Force the user to have MSBuild in their PATH.** This doesn't have the drawbacks of the previous option, but again I don't want to force my contributors to have to configure anything because I'm betting most of them would opt out if I did that.
- **Pass the path to MSBuild as a command-line parameter.** Again, while this is a lot lower-maintenance than some of the other options, I'd rather not have users enter the path to the executable every time they wanted to build.

Is there an alternative that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your 5th option is fine, just cache the path that's passed so the user doesn't have to spell it out every time.

Sample build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptroot="$(cd "$(dirname $0)" && pwd -P)"
cachefile="$scriptroot/$(basename $0).cache"

if [ ! -z $1 ]
then
    msbuildpath=$1/MSBuild.exe
    echo $msbuildpath > $cachefile
elif [ -e $cachefile ]
then
    msbuildpath=$(cat $cachefile)
else
    echo "Please specify the directory containing MSBuild."
fi

# To use: $msbuildpath (or mono $msbuildpath) foo.csproj
```

Comment: This question and its answer do not match IMHO. To build something on non-Windows platforms, so far you can only use `xbuild` from Mono, while Microsoft is quickly moving .NET Core and MSBuild for .NET Core to such platforms. The shell script attempts to execute MSBuild.exe directly, which is what I concerned the most. From where did you get that executable? I don't think you can directly use the one from Windows side.

Comment: @LexLi This used to be what I thought as well, but it turns out that since MSBuild is written in C#, it's not actual machine code that's contained in the file, but IL that's not tied to a particular OS.

Comment: It is the licensing of the binaries as well as the design on Windows file paths that I am concerned.